# Taxonomist badge with only 14 questions.

Tags: bug, status-completed

I saw the first silver badge was awarded. It was a [taxonomist](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/badges/11/taxonomist) badge awarded to the tag [card-games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/card-games). But there are only 14 questions with this tag. Is this a bug or has there been a lot of retagging going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect this is when `Svisstack` spammed the forums with his poker questions.  There are a few of his questions still around, and they use the `card-games` tag.

I know Svisstack got a few Taxonomist badges before he was suspended and deleted, and while it looks like someone took away *his* Taxonomoist badges, anyone else who earned one from his tag use still has them.

Comment: Ok, sounds reasonable.